# Define components inside TabPanel dynamically (material-ui, react)

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui

I'm receiving the information of the tabs to render from an array, for example: ['general','whodas','tasks']. From this information, I have to create TabPanel labels which contains the component that has to be displayed. For instance, for general the label should be like that:

```
<TabPanel  value={tab.elementIndex} index={tab.elementIndex}>
  <Dashboard></Dashboard>
</TabPanel>
```

I'm creating an array with all the information the elementIndex and the component to render, that looks like this:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {component: "dashboard", elementIndex: 0}
1: {component: "whodas", elementIndex: 1}
2: {component: "resources", elementIndex: 2}
3: {component: "tasks", elementIndex: 3}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

And then try to render it in the return:

```
<Fragment>
          {tabsPanelHtml!== undefined ? tabsPanelHtml.map ((tab) =>{
            
            if(tab.component === 'dashboard') {
              return(
                <TabPanel  value={tab.elementIndex} index={tab.elementIndex}>
                  <Dashboard></Dashboard>
                </TabPanel>
    
              )
            } else if (tab.component === 'whodas') {
              return(
                <TabPanel  value={tab.elementIndex} index={tab.elementIndex}>
                  <WhoDas></WhoDas>
                </TabPanel>
    
              )
            } else if (tab.component === 'resources') {
              return(
                <TabPanel  value={tab.elementIndex} index={tab.elementIndex}>
                  <ResourcesInfo></ResourcesInfo>
                </TabPanel>
    
              )
            } else if (tab.component === 'tasks') {
              return(
                <TabPanel  value={tab.elementIndex} index={tab.elementIndex}>
                  <Tasks></Tasks>
                </TabPanel>
    
              )
            } else if (tab.component === 'newAdalmed') {
              return(
                <TabPanel  value={tab.elementIndex} index={tab.elementIndex}>
                  <NewAdalmed></NewAdalmed>
                </TabPanel>
    
              )
            }
          

          })

          : null}
        </Fragment>
```

But then, it appears that there is nothing to render:
[image]

I think there's something incorrect in my rendering approach (surprise)

Comment: This part of the code works fine. The problem is coming from another part of your code. Can you share some part of your code online in the sandbox?

Comment: Hi @alisasani! This is my Tabs component: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-dubinsky-su4c7?file=/src/TabsContainer.jsx Is that part what you mean? Thanks!